How and why did Kant’s distinction of noumena and phenomena come about at that point in intellectual history?
What was it that caused philosophers to reflect on a differentiation between things as they are, and things as they are perceived?
Did then-recent science expose people to the idea that the world perceived around them may not be “the true world” - for example, did results in physics expose people to the idea that the world is partially unperceived?
What was the build-up to this precipitous idea?

Kant's project to reconcile rationalism (Leibniz) with empiricism (Locke, Hume).

The idea has been around for quite some time and Kant based his noumenon-phenomenon distinction mainly on Leibnizian philosophy.
This - Leibnizian and rationalist - philosophy basically found its peak in the main works of Christian Wolff, who was widely known and praised in and beyond Germany when Kant began his philosophical studies. Thus, the distinction has been around for quite some time (even before Leibniz) and at the same time part of mainstream philosophy at his time.
At the same time, translations of Hume became available in Germany, Hume who "woke" Kant "from [his] dogmatic [Leibnizian] slumber", as his famous citation from the introduction to his first critique says. Hume put the cornerstones of Wolffian philosophy in peril of crumbling and every systematic philosophy with it.
That is where the noumenal-phenomenal distinction comes into play since Kant realised that this might provide a solution for the tension between Wolffian aspirations and Humean challenges. The famous antinomies of the first critique show exactly this.
Hence, it is exactly this point because "dogmatic" systematic philosophy was at its peak and suddenly met with skeptical/empiricist challenges that needed to be addressed.
